# URL redirect to port

Tags: url, port, redirect

I have set up SAB, Sickbeard, CouchPotato & Plex on my home media server. All mapped to respective ports.

The ports have been forwarded correctly and I have DDNS enabled, if I browse to my DDNS address proceeded by the port number - I can access my services absolutely fine.

What I am wanting to do is use sub-domains on a domain that I already own to make the URLs a bit more friendly. However I have tried setting up simple web redirects & these don't work for some reason.

For example;

**sab.domain.com** = DDNS_address:9090 
**plex.domain.com** = DDNS_address:32400/web/index.html

When trying to access I get *404 Not Found* errors.

I don't host my own IIS or Apache server, the domain is hosted by an online provider.

Is this possible or worth too much hassle?

Thanks.